# How to change default region in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using SQS for apache airflow.The setup running quiet well for now.

But the default region is us-east-1 , how can we change the default region?

I have added the config parameter `region=us-west-2` to the `[celery_broker_transport_options]` and `[celery]` sections ,but it doesnt work, the default region is still `us-east-1` .

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying the wrong key name:

```
[celery_broker_transport_options]
region = us-west-2
```

See the Celery docs for the key name (`region`) [1] and the Airflow configuration code for the section name (`celery_broker_transport_options`) [2].

[1] http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html

[2] https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_celery.py#L50

Comment: Oops...it was a typo...Actually I had tried region=us-west-2   and it didnt work..Thanks for pointing it :)